# Unable to access a global variable

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

I'm trying to exec some code in a specific environment where I have imported some of its dependencies, but I keep getting an error saying that the module can't be found. I have opened up a debugger, and I see the module in the global environment, but when I try to access the module using normal scoping methods, python can't seem to find it.

```
(Pdb) globals['my_import']
<module 'tmp0fZtOs' from '/tmp/tmp0fZtOs.py'>
(Pdb) my_import
*** NameError: name 'my_import' is not defined
```

I also found some documentation that mentioned that global variables need to be explicitly referenced in order to make them available to a function, but when I try something like the following, I also get an error.

```
(Pdb) def temp_function(): global my_import; print my_import
(Pdb) temp_function()
*** NameError: global name 'my_import' is not defined
```

Any ideas on what I might able to do in order to make this module available to my exec'ed code?

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: `globals['my_import']` ?  Did you mean `globals()['my_import']` ?

Comment: I used globals['my_import'] because globals is a dictionary. If I try to use globals()['my_import'], I get an error saying that a dictionary is not callable.

Comment: `globals` is a built-in function which returns a dictionary. `globals()[variable_name]` should give you the varaible `variable_name`. That is, until you create your own variable named `globals`, thus hiding the built-in `globals`. It looks like you did that here. That seems to be where your prblems started, but you did not post that part of your code...

Comment: Whatever this `globals` thing is, it's neither the Python built-in nor this code's actual global variable dict.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but in the process of creating a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example, the error stopped reproducing. I removed all of my changes in order to get back to the original code, and the original code works now. I'll comment again if this error shows up again, but for now I just want to thank everybody for the extremely fast responses.

Answer (score -1):

You declared `my_import` to be global, but you didn't assign it a value, therefore, it does not exist.

```
def temp_function(): 
    global my_import
    my_import = 1
    print(my_import)

temp_function()
if "my_import" in globals().keys():
    print("Variable is global")
    print(globals()['my_import'])
```

Comment: I'm not trying to initialize a new global variable, I'm trying to access one that I know already exists.

Comment: "You initialized your global variable but you didn't assign it a value." - that's not actually possible under Python's execution model. There's no such thing as an initialized but valueless variable. (It's possible to have a *local* variable that *exists* without a value, but not any sort of variable that's *initialized* without having a value.)

Comment: Also, don't call `keys`.

Comment: Without calling `keys`, you get an error. For instance: `"a" in gloabls().keys` will produce an error while `"a" in globals().keys()` will not.

Comment: @JoshSmith: `"a" in globals()`, on the other hand, is correct, shorter, and faster than using `keys`. Particularly, on Python 2, using `keys` is catastrophic for performance, since it builds a list and iterates over it to look for the key.